# Observing data on Firebase vs. checking an array?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I've got a situation where I've got a tableview being filled with names from Firebase.

When the view loads in, I pull all the necessary names from firebase, load them into an array, and base my tableview off that array.

I have an "add" button that takes whatever's in a text field and adds that name to both firebase and their list.

What I do not want to allow is for people to add a name that they have already added.

I'm pulling the names they've added from Firebase like:

```
users
   209384092834
        Names
           Bob
           Sue
```

so if the user were to type in Rob, it'd add it under that "names" bit, but if they typed in Bob/Sue it wouldn't allow them to add that again.

The two ways I see of doing this are to check if the name a user is wanting to add is in the array I'm filling on load, or to check against the names that are under their Names child on firebase.

Are there any strong arguments for using one over the other. Is it a "big deal" to run an observer to firebase? I feel like using firebase here is "safer" than checking the array..like what if the users net is so or inturrupts, the array hasn't filled up yet, and they type in a name to add, add it, and everything is just a mess. I don't even know if something like that COULD happen.

Any advice here on which direction to take and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Important :- Never use `Arrays` or `Tuples` to store in Firebase Database, always prefer Dictionary

Make your DB look something like this :-

```
{ users : {
  209384092834 : {
    Names: {
       Bob  : True,
       Sue  : True 
           }
         }
    }
 }
```

I would suggest you use a third path :-

Check if that name exists by referring to that child node and checking by taking a particular snap of that path instead of the entire list..

```
rootRef.child("users").child(timeStamp).child("Names").child(textField.text!).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {(snapshotRecieved) in
 if snapshotRecieved.exists()
 {
  //Show Alert that user Exists i.e if user is rob/sue in your case
  }else{
    let ref = rootRef.child("users").child(timeStamp).child("Names")
      ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {(snapshot) in

         if let namesDict = snapshot!.value as? NSMutableDictionary{

              namesDict.setObject("True",forKey:textField.text!)
              ref.setValue(namesDict)
          }
       })
     } 
 })
```